# Possible SSD failure after overclock

Tags: ssd, overclocking, boot

I (foolishly) attempted an overclock on my newly-upgraded (new mobo and SSD) rig, and now I cannot boot. The relevant components:

- AMD Phenom II X4 965 - 3.4Ghz (overclocked 10%)
- Kingston HyperX DDR3 1600 1.65V 2x4GB (overclocked 10%, overvolted to 1.685V)
- Intel 520 series 120GB SSD

Immediately after changing the settings in BIOS, my computer would not POST. After manually resetting the BIOS, the computer POSTs fine but blue screen's whenever I try to boot Windows 7. Furthermore, if I launch system repair I get the error SystemRepairOffline, and if I try to use System Restore that fails as well. Yet it boots fine from an external USB, passes all memory tests, and chkdsk returns no errors. The only other thing I can think of trying is booting from an external USB, copying all my files off the drive and then re-installing Windows. Is that what it comes to?

What is going on here?

Comment: You could be looking a memory error. I don't think you damaged anything. When you reset the Bios to default, did it set your ram back to 1.5V? Because it should be set to 1.65V or you might have problems. I run my Ram at 1.65V and 1333MHz otherwise I have issues. You may want to get a Memtest86 test CD.

Comment: @cloneman I set the voltage back to 1.65V, and besides the ram passed a full windows memtest. I actually got my rig working again by reinstalling windows, but I'm leaving this up in case anyone can tell me what happened.

Answer (score 1):

When you reset the BIOS, the SATA controller might have changed modes from AHCI to IDE (or vice versa).  If this is the case, then the system will POST okay, but when Windows tries to start up, it will die with a blue-screen "inaccessible boot device".  Try the several options for the SATA controller in your BIOS.